# Bootstrap Drop down button not dropping down

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So I added a drop down button at the end of my table, and for some reason when I click on it, nothing drops down. I see no errors on my console either. Is there something in my CSS that could be preventing it from working?

HTML Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="public/stylesheets/grayscale.css">
  <title>tech</title>
</head>

<body>
<div id="Tech" class="header">
  <center><img src="public/images/test.png" id='Logo' alt="Logo">
  </center>
</div>

<form id="upload" action="index.html" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<fieldset>
<input type="hidden" id="MAX_FILE_SIZE" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="300000" />
<div>
    <div id="filedrag"> 
        <img src="public/images/upload3.png" alt="draganddrop"> 
    </div>
    <input type="file" id="fileselect" name="fileselect[]" multiple="multiple"/>
</div>
</fieldset>
</form>

<div id="messages">
</div>

<table id="data-table" class="container">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>
        <h3>Video</h3>
      </th>
      <th>
        <h3>Original Size</h3>
      </th>
      <th>
        <h3>Compressed Size</h3>
      </th>
      <th>
        <h3>Compressed rate</h3>
      </th>
      <th>
        <h3>Savings</h3>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Video1 File Name</td>
      <td>Original File Size</td>
      <td>6369</td>
      <td>01:32:50</td>
      <td>450</td>      
      <td>
        <div class="container">
          <div class="dropdown">
            <button class="btn btn-success dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Compress
            <span class="caret"></span></button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#">Compress</a></li>
              <li class="disabled"><a href="#">Download</a></li>
              <li class="active"><a href="#">Delete</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>        
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Video 2 File Name</td>
      <td>Original File Size</td>
      <td>10437</td>
      <td>00:51:22</td>
      <td>450</td>
      <td>
        <div class="container">
          <div class="dropdown">
            <button class="btn btn-success dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Compress
            <span class="caret"></span></button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#">Compress</a></li>
              <li class="disabled"><a href="#">Download</a></li>
              <li class="active"><a href="#">Delete</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>               
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Video 3 File Name</td>
      <td>Original File Size</td>
      <td>5327</td>
      <td>00:24:34</td>
      <td>450</td>
      <td>
        <div class="container">
          <div class="dropdown">
            <button class="btn btn-success dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Compress
            <span class="caret"></span></button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#">Compress</a></li>
              <li class="disabled"><a href="#">Download</a></li>
              <li class="active"><a href="#">Delete</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>        
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

</body>
<script src="public/js/filedrag.js"></script>
</html>
```

CSS Code:

```
@charset "UTF-8";
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,700);

body {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  line-height: 1.42em;
  color:#A7A1AE;
  background-color:#1F2739;
}

.data-table{
    margin-top: 250px;
}

#filedrag{
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 7px;
    cursor: default;
}

#filedrag.hover{
    color: #f00;
    border-color: #f00;
    border-style: solid;
    box-shadow: inset 0 3px 4px #888;
}

#title{
    text-align: center;
}

#logo{
    float: right;
}

.header img {
    float:left;
    border: 5px;
    padding:5px;
    width: 4em;
    height: 4em;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.header h1 {
  position:relative;
  font-size:3em; 
  font-weight: 300;
  line-height:1em;
  text-align: left;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

h1 {
  font-size:3em; 
  font-weight: 300;
  line-height:1em;
  text-align: center;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

h2 {
  font-size:1em; 
  font-weight: 300;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  line-height:1em;
  padding-bottom: 2em;
  color: #FB667A;
}

h2 a {
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #FB667A;
  text-decoration: none;
}

h3{
    color: white;
}

h4{
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 2em;
}

#Register
{
    margin-left: 750px;
    margin-top: 27px;
}
.btn-update{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    margin-bottom: 300px;
    margin-left: -65px;
}

.hideshow{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    margin-bottom: 300px;
    margin-left: -65px;
}

.blue { color: #185875; }
.yellow { color: #FFF842; }

.container th h1 {
      font-weight: bold;
      font-size: 1em;
  text-align: left;
  color: #185875;
}

.container td {
      font-weight: normal;
      font-size: 1em;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 2px -2px #0E1119;
       -moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 2px -2px #0E1119;
            box-shadow: 0 2px 2px -2px #0E1119;
}

.container {
      text-align: left;
      overflow: hidden;
      width: 80%;
      margin: 0 auto;
  display: table;
  padding: 0 0 8em 0;
}

.container td, .container th {
    padding-bottom: 2%;
    padding-top: 2%;
    padding-left:2%;  
}

/* Background-color of the odd rows */
.container tr:nth-child(odd) {
      background-color: #323C50;
}

/* Background-color of the even rows */
.container tr:nth-child(even) {
      background-color: #2C3446;
}

.container th {
      background-color: #1F2739;
}

.container_graph {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 15px auto;
  margin-top: 175px;
}

.container td:first-child { color: #FB667A; }

.container tr:hover {
   background-color: #464A52;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 6px 6px -6px #0E1119;
       -moz-box-shadow: 0 6px 6px -6px #0E1119;
            box-shadow: 0 6px 6px -6px #0E1119;
}

.container td:hover {
  /*background-color: #FFF842;*/
  /*color: #403E10;*/


  transition-delay: 0s;
      transition-duration: 0.4s;
      transition-property: all;
  transition-timing-function: line;
}

@media (max-width: 800px) {
.container td:nth-child(4),
.container th:nth-child(4) { display: none; }
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Look at the below snippet it works fine. Add the cdn's in the below mentioned order.

```
<link rel="stylesheet"   
href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
          <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
          <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
           <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
           <style type="text/css">
             

           </style>
           </head>
           <body>
           <div id="Tech" class="header">
  <center><img src="public/images/test.png" id='Logo' alt="Logo">
  </center>
</div>

<form id="upload" action="index.html" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<fieldset>
<input type="hidden" id="MAX_FILE_SIZE" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="300000" />
<div>
    <div id="filedrag"> 
        <img src="public/images/upload3.png" alt="draganddrop"> 
    </div>
    <input type="file" id="fileselect" name="fileselect[]" multiple="multiple"/>
</div>
</fieldset>
</form>

<div id="messages">
</div>

<table id="data-table" class="container">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>
        <h3>Video</h3>
      </th>
      <th>
        <h3>Original Size</h3>
      </th>
      <th>
        <h3>Compressed Size</h3>
      </th>
      <th>
        <h3>Compressed rate</h3>
      </th>
      <th>
        <h3>Savings</h3>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Video1 File Name</td>
      <td>Original File Size</td>
      <td>6369</td>
      <td>01:32:50</td>
      <td>450</td>      
      <td>
        <div class="container">
          <div class="dropdown">
            <button class="btn btn-success dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Compress
            <span class="caret"></span></button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#">Compress</a></li>
              <li class="disabled"><a href="#">Download</a></li>
              <li class="active"><a href="#">Delete</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>        
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Video 2 File Name</td>
      <td>Original File Size</td>
      <td>10437</td>
      <td>00:51:22</td>
      <td>450</td>
      <td>
        <div class="container">
          <div class="dropdown">
            <button class="btn btn-success dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Compress
            <span class="caret"></span></button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#">Compress</a></li>
              <li class="disabled"><a href="#">Download</a></li>
              <li class="active"><a href="#">Delete</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>               
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Video 3 File Name</td>
      <td>Original File Size</td>
      <td>5327</td>
      <td>00:24:34</td>
      <td>450</td>
      <td>
        <div class="container">
          <div class="dropdown">
            <button class="btn btn-success dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Compress
            <span class="caret"></span></button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#">Compress</a></li>
              <li class="disabled"><a href="#">Download</a></li>
              <li class="active"><a href="#">Delete</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>        
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: Just added that, but still for some reason, it still isn't dropping down. Do you think it could be something in my CSS preventing it?

Comment: No your css has no reference to your dropdown button. remove all other linkinging files meaning script and css except bootstrap cdn's from your page . after that run your code see the same problem is occuring or not.

Comment: yea I just removed everything except for bootstrap cdn's and it works. Just have to figure out which one is giving me trouble. Thanks!

Comment: I think it's your javascript file..'<script src="public/js/filedrag.js"></script>'. I think it has some reference to your toggle button.Hope this helps!

Comment: ok this is giving me trouble :   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="public/stylesheets/grayscale.css">

Comment: Just remove the style related to dropdown button. seewhat happens.

Comment: ok I was messing around in my css and I believe it is this code that is causing this problem. When I remove this, I can use the drop down just fine....container {
   text-align: left;
   overflow: hidden;
   width: 80%;
   margin: 0 auto;
  display: table;
  padding: 0 0 8em 0;
}

Comment: Great that you figured it out!

Comment: Thanks! now to just figure out what exactly about this is causing the problem haha. Anyway, thanks guys

Comment: Incase any one was curios, it was the overflow section of the css code!

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to load bootstrap.js as well, as the dropdown needs bootstrap.js to function.

The css file is mainly to style the controls, but the real interaction is handled by the JavaScript file.

Comment: sorry I'm still a little new at this. By load bootstrap.js, what do you mean exactly?


edit: I have a bootstrap folder I dowloaded from the website in my main folder, is that all I have to do?

Comment: Bootstrap have two files that it needs - the bootstrap.css, and bootstrap.js. You need to add the <script> tag that loads bootstrap.js file as well (it should be after the jquery script tag in your html)

Comment: @KarthikKomatineni http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#download-cdn It doesn't matter if you load the files from `cdn` or from local folder. You still need to load all three. Right now you are missing `bootstrap.js` (or `bootstrap.min.js`) - you can use any of them. Make sure you load it after `jquery.min.js`.

Comment: so I added these two lines:   <script type='text/js' href='bootstrap-3.3.7-dist/js/bootstrap' type="text/javascript"></script>
and also   <script type='text/js' href='bootstrap-3.3.7-dist/js/bootstrap.min' type="text/javascript"></script>.....so these are referring to my bootstrap file I downloaded in my main folder, this should do it right?

Comment: You just need one of them. The .min is just a minified (smaller file size) version

Comment: oh ok, just removed one of them. For some reason how ever, my button is still not functioning properly.

Comment: Just make sure it is placed after the jquery.js

Answer (score 0):

Add these dependencies, right before the ending `</body>` tag,

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Hello, please notice this question is 5 years old, and it was about bootstrap V3. Existing answers already addressed the issue, I recommend the deletion of this answer.

Comment: Hi great comment, however I disagree with your recommendation and hope developers downloading the new version will find my answer helpful. Cheers!

Comment: Ok, I understand your good intentions. It would be useful if you could edit your answer adding a little introduction, something like "For those who have the same issue with bootstrap V4, here is my solution: ...". Thank you for contributing.